# Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php on line 290

Tags: magento2, error

In magento 2 i am enable developer mode, all things are working good but today

Its give me this error

> Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php on line 290

When i am disable developer mode its working properly, i don't understand why this error generate suddenly

i want to enable developer mode,is there any solution?

Comment: When you are on developer mode.You need to use -f with your command.
Like this: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f.

Comment: I am facing same issue. and issue happen some time in production mode and after some time it's fixed automatically. what's wrong with apache sometime?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in developer mode. Following steps solved my problems:

1. change your application mode to "production"

   Command:

   ```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
   ```
2. run the command to deploy static view contents

   Command:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
3. Change your application mode back to "developer"

Those steps should solve the problem as it works absolutely fine for me.

Comment: As soon as developer mode is enabled, it goes back to the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Below solution worked for me.

Restart Apache Server. After this run below command :

> **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`**

Comment: why need to "Restart Apache Server." ?? what's wrong with apache some time??

Answer (score 2):

Restart Your Apache Server & After this run below command :

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: why need to "Restart Apache Server." ?? what's wrong with apache some time??

Comment: This is actual issue in server cache. So, When you restart apache2 Server cache would be clean. As well as Nginx server too.

Comment: thanx for response. but I want to know reason of issue. why apache server show issue? I want to fix it permanent bases. our site showing it once in week.

Comment: For Permanent solution you have to turn on Magento Production Mode. It would help you on both way:
1. Error not shown on frontend it would be write in the logs.
2. Site Speed will be up more than 30% from development mode.
Also, Development mode is use for development to show error on runtime.

Comment: Production mode already set and that's why it's not showing error but showing "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. Could not write error message to log. Please use developer mode to see the message." but it's not wrinting anything in log. so I changed site to developer mode and find this Dom.php related error. now I want to fix it permanent basis

Comment: error showing for few minutes and again after site started to work. it's happend twice in last 15 days. so, I want permanent solution. If you know about this issue please explain about possible solution or possible cause of error