# How to remove Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema

Tags: error, magento2.3.1, localhost

When I run my  magento 2.3.1 ver. on localhost in morning then comes below error

Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema

So please let me help.

Comment: can you please restart server and than upgrade command.

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110994/warning-domdocumentschemavalidate-invalid-schema-in-magento-framework-conf

Answer (score 0):

Please set production mode by skipping the compilation. Then again you can set the developer mode once the deploy command completed.

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

php bin/magento s:s:d

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer